# Creating high resolution DEM file from points (path) in google earth using QGIS?

Tags: dem, google-earth, mapping

I am having trouble trying to create a DEM file from points in Google Earth. I followed all the steps to export a .kml from Google Earth to then import a delimited text layer that I turn into a .shape file, then run the saga - natural neighbor algorithm in QGIS. when I do though it creates a DEM but the resolution is really poor, the image size is only 108x84 px!

Is there a way to make the DEM or height map a higher resolution like 4K?

I am trying to get a high resolution height map to use in 3D app to build an accurate model of the Giza Plateau for a project. The USGS 30m sat data DEM is not close enough to the terrain to map the details.

Followed this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JMbbm-X8fI8

Or if there is a way to create a high res DEM from a topographic map image such as the one attached, maybe trace the lines and turn it into vector in QGIS?

There has to be a way to pull a high resolution heigh map from some source thats better then sat data at 30m, if it was in US I could pull higher res DEM from USGS, but its Egypt.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101296/discussion-on-question-by-kevin-alves-creating-high-resolution-dem-file-from-poi).